# Boostrap Responsive Navbar Collapse Button Not Working Due to Custom CSS

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I have created a html page using bootstrap and then converted it into wordpress and added some custom css later on.

At first, in html version the navbar collapse button was working perfectly when i resized my screen. But later (i guess after editing the custom css) the collapse buttons are not working anymore.

PROBLEM: When i resize my screen the navbar links transform into a clickable button (good) but if i click on it, menu items are not revealed (BAD).

The site is: http://farmersmarketdirect.org

How can i solve this problem please?

Comment: I get a 404 on http://farmersmarketdirect.org/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the bootstrap js file is not loaded properly, this is what the javascript console shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://farmersmarketdirect.org/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot to add the template directory in the JS url. This fixed the problem. 

Anyway, how do i check for these errors myself? Thanks

Comment: For example in Chrome you can open console by pressing Ctrl + Shift + J. Other browsers have these tools too.